# How do you customize the location of Postgres databases on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos7, postgresql-9.2

I am using CentOS 7.3 as a guest VM from Oracle VirtualBox. The host is Windows 7 and I have a physical USB stick (aka flash drive) to house the data directory for Postgres.  I can use a USB stick as a mounted directory in Linux. I can read and write files to it.

I expect to be able to have Postgres databases on my USB stick.  But I cannot get Postgres databases on my USB stick.  I installed Postgres on the Linux VM.

To change the default data directory of Postgres, I followed these [directions](http://community.cloud66.com/articles/how-to-change-the-data-directory-for-postgresql).

If you do not have time to go to the link, I simply installed Postgres with these two commands:

```
yum -y install postgresql-server postgresql-contrib

postgresql-setup initdb
```

then I ran these two commands:

```
mv /var/lib/pgsql/data/* /mnt/windows-share/data

ln -s /mnt/windows-share /var/lib/pgsql/data
```

Afterward I try to start the Postgres service, I get an error.

Here is the command that I try (as root):

systemctl start postgresql

Here is the error:

> Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited
>   with error code.  See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and
>   "journalctl -xe" for detail.

I tried `systemctl status postgresql.service` and I found this:

> Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled
>   vendorpreset: disabled)
>
> Active: failed (Result exit-code)... Process ...
>   ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited,
>   status=1/FAILURE)
>
> ... failed to start PostgreSQL... ...Unit postgresql.service...
>   ...postgresql.service failed

I used `journalctl -xe` but that did not tell me anything meaningful.

To change the default data directory of Postgres, I tried this:

```
postgresql-setup initdb --pgdata=/mnt/windows-share/
```

But I got

> failed to find PGDATA setting in --pgdata=/mnt/mar/data.service

How do I get Postgres installed with a customized data directory?  I need it to be in a the "/mnt/" directory.  I want to create all my databases on a USB stick.

Comment: Is the postgres user in the correct group to access shared folders?

Answer (score 2):

To install Postgres on a customized location (e.g. home/postgres directory) follow these steps

install the required version of Postgres e.g. 13
create postgres directory in Home. and grant its access to posgres user

```
mkdir postgres
chown postgres:postgres postgres
usermod -m -d /home/postgres postgres
```

Move data directory to the new location as:

```
rsync -av /var/lib/pgsql/ /home/postgres/
```

update the location in postgres server as:

```
find / -name postgresql-9.5.service
vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.5.service
```

update the data location in the file:

from the old location, e.g.

```
# Location of database directory
Environment=PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/13/data/
```

to the new location, e.g.

```
# Location of database directory
Environment=PGDATA=/home/postgres/13/data/"
```

Stop postgres, reload deamon and start postgres

```
stop postgres
systemctl daemon-reload
start postgres
```

Done...

Answer (score 0):

I' ve solved the same problem on CentOS 6 
Maybe u can try it.

1. Add your disk
2. Check your disk is existing (in my case new disk is /dev/sdb1/)

   ```
   # fdisk -l
   ```
3. Mount new disk

   ```
   # mkdir /hdd2
   ```

   ```
   # mount -t ext3 /dev/sdb1 /hdd2/
   ```
4. Auto mount hard disk by add new line:

   ```
   # vi /etc/fstab
   Add line: /dev/sdb1  /hdd2  ext3  defaults 0 0
   ```
5. Config postgres

   ```
   # service postgresql stop
   ```

   ```
   # vi /etc/sysconfig/pgsql/postgresql
   Add line: PGDATA=/hdd2/data
   ```

   ```
   # service postgresql start
   ```

Hope it useful to you!!

Comment: I have no file "/etc/sysconfig/pgsql/postgresql".  I have these files:
1) /run/postgresql 2) /etc/selinux/targetd/active/modules/100/postgresql
3) /etc/pam.d/postgresql 4) /usr/libexec/initscripts/legacy-actions/postgresql       What should I do?

Comment: @Alex111 Your system is Redhat, right ?? You can try config at this path `3) /etc/pam.d/postgresql ` . Please let me know if u have anything.